# Android app icon is too small on some phone

Tags: java, android, icons

For example, my app icon looks like the one on the right. I have configured square and round icons on AndroidManifest.xml and put each variation in mipmap folders for different sizes.

How do I fix this issue (that is to look like the one on left)?

my AndroidManifest.xml.

```
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round">
```

[image]

Comment: have you added ```adaptive icon``` ? Checkout this link to understand how you can add and use https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/icon_design_adaptive